# Unable to convert error after Xamarin Forms upgrade

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working in an old mobile application developed with Prism 6.3.0. I've updated the Xamarin Forms version from 2.3.5.256-pre6 to 4.8.0.1687.
I changed also the Target Framework version from 8 to 10, the same in Android Manifest targetSdkVersion from 26 to 29.
After these update, in the class MainActivity at this row:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

I have this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  Message=Unable to convert instance of type 'Google.Android.Material.Snackbar.Snackbar+SnackbarLayout' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.
```

I tried to delete bin and obj folders and reboot Visual Studio 2019 but without success. What I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: You are trying to cast a Layout to a ToolBar?

Comment: No, I don't have an explicit cast to ToolBar

Comment: That is what the error message says.  You need to create a toolbar item.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem

Comment: Hi, have a try with updating all the nuget packages by [select all packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPiB2.png). Not updating only one nugetpackage or update them one by one. Because this will make them be conflict when installing.

Comment: I solved the issue by renaming toolbar.xml into Toolbar.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by renaming toolbar.xml into Toolbar.xml.

The file is in the folder Resources\layout